# How to extend method Base.∘ in Julia

Tags: julia

I'm trying to extend the method `Base.∘`.

Trying to define

```
function Base.∘(f₁::Transformation, f₂::Transformation)
    println("baz")
end
```

Gives the following error:

```
syntax: expected "end" in definition of function "Base"
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I extend it?

Comment: Try to add a colon: `function Base.:∘(...) ... end`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
function Base.:∘(f₁::Transformation, f₂::Transformation)
    println("baz")
end
```

Comment: Is this answer still applicable for 1.x? For extending `==` I need to write `Base.:(==)`, something which is somehow hard to find. (And hard to remember, apparently.)